# Does this answer answer the question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I had a review audit (don't worry, my post isn't about the actual audit) that gave me this answer in the First Posts queue:

[image: answer]

It was really badly worded, so I tried to edit to improve but I was told that I couldn't because the post was deleted. (Big clue that it was an audit :P)

[This is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26782289/cargo-plugin-not-pasted-war-file-in-tomcat-web-apps-location). I can't see the deleted answer on that page nor vote to undelete because I don't have enough rep.

But it looks to me like the question is saying

> "My war file isn't in the tomcat web app folder, what have I done wrong?"

and the answer is saying

> "Your war file has been put in this other place instead."

(The way it's worded, the two users might even be the same person and OP might be answering their own question. But that's speculation.)

I think the unclear wording may have caused users to vote to incorrectly delete it as Not An Answer (for those that can't see, it has a default *This does not provide an answer to the question* comment, so I don't think it was deleted by its owner).

I was going to flag for mod attention, but the question and answer aren't in my area of expertise and I thought I might be missing something. Am I?

Comment: Looks like it went through the Low Quality Review queue, and enough people felt it was vague enough to warrant being deleted.  Once it was deleted, it became a candidate for an audit.  It *seems* like it could be an answer, but I haven't had my coffee yet.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I'm not bothered about the audit part at all, I just had to include that to explain how I was able to view a deleted answer with only 802 rep. My question is about whether the answer should have been deleted, and whether it should remain deleted.

Comment: Yeah, I dunno... it's not the greatest answer, but I've seen worse answers go undeleted.  I probably wouldn't have voted to delete it, but that's just me.... curious what others have to say.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables It really doesn't convey the information well at all (hence why I wanted to edit it), but I do believe that the information is there, and that it's not unclear (well, it's unclear in delivery, but the actual details don't seem unclear). There are also no other (visible) answers to the question.

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715645/using-gradle-cargo-plugin-to-deploy-to-multiple-environments) cleanly answered by one commenter, so if he don't get the issue, I assume no-one will. the question is double (where are the war (but it's a XY problem, the OP just don't get its app and troubleshoot like mickey sorcerer's apprentice) and then wonder which port it should give in it's conf. Definitively not an answer to OP root problem, it could have be a comment on the war location itslef.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables for the sake of completeness, I would add that besides (possibly incorrect) reviewers evaluation, answerer themselves [did not care](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184568/165773): "post authors can always undelete posts deleted by low-rep users via /review..." Using such posts in review audits is really slippery idea, one can't tell anything about the post where nobody cared enough, it could be good or bad or anything in between

Comment: I don't know if it is good enough to be called an answer, but I think that the information could be useful for the OP. It should probably be a comment, at least.

Comment: @gnat: TIL! That is most reassuring. (Also, bizarre how very seldom that appears to be taken advantage of. Oh well.)